# Keeping method bodies closed netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Looking for a way to achieve either of the two below in Netbeans:

- Keeping method bodies open/closed throughout opening and closing of Netbeans
- Have method bodies closed by default when opening Netbeans

If anyone knows if this is possible or not that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either manually in your code:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="your own description">
  ...any code...
// </editor-fold>
```

Or under

```
Tools / Options / Editor / Folding
```

select what (membery, comments, etc.) should be collapsed by default.